# sed: keep certain contents for matched lines

Tags: sed, fasta

I have numerous sequences in one fasta file like the one below (downloaded from UniProtKB):

```
>sp|P00045|CYC7_YEAST Cytochrome c iso-2 OS=Saccharomyces cerevisiae (strain ATCC 204508 / S288c) GN=CYC7 PE=1 SV=1
MAKESTGFKPGSAKKGATLFKTRCQQCHTIEEGGPNKVGPNLHGIFGRHSGQVKGYSYTD
ANINKNVKWDEDSMSEYLTNPKKYIPGTKMAFAGLKKEKDRNDLITYMTKAAK
```

Since they are all amino acid sequences for cytochrome c, I care only about the organism (i.e. *Saccharomyces cerevisiae* for the above entry). So I wish to modify headers of these sequences as below:

```
>Saccharomyces cerevisiae
MAKESTGFKPGSAKKGATLFKTRCQQCHTIEEGGPNKVGPNLHGIFGRHSGQVKGYSYTD
ANINKNVKWDEDSMSEYLTNPKKYIPGTKMAFAGLKKEKDRNDLITYMTKAAK
```

Organism names always come after "OS=" and stop when either one of:

1. space(.*) # strain information
2. space..=

is met.

So could anybody give me some clues on how to make it? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sed 's/.*OS=\([^(]*\).*/>\1/' input
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I forgot to address that I am using sed on mac but not a GNU one (returns "sed: illegal option -- r"). And it seems that this command cannot recognize the case when there is no (.*), like the one below: >sp|P62895|CYC_PIG Cytochrome c OS=Sus scrofa GN=CYCS PE=1 SV=2

Comment: dropped `-r`. can you try it again?

Comment: You'd need to escape the `+` too: `\+`.

Comment: BSD sed doesn't understand `\+`. Use `\{1,\}`. Or use `-E` and extended regex, that's probably nicer. EDIT: In fact, just use `*`.

Comment: @Wintermute Yes since the name can't be empty * is ok. Or just use GNU/Linux!! :). I'm currently about to collect all the sed versions and create a script which outputs results for all the versions. I started this week, but had a lot of other things to do.. (starting a new job).. Probably it would be even more fun if we - the guys who are frequently active on the `sed`, `awk`, `shell` ... - tags would create it together... As a final result an online tool would be great. But when making shell scripts executable from remote, I would really appreciate help and suggests from you guys anyway...

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks, I solve this by appending one more sed command: `sed 's/\ ..=.*//'  input`  And also thank you @wintermute @EdMorton. I will be excited to hear that such a script comes out.